# Foundation components not compiling

Tags: css, zurb-foundation

I cloned a clean copy of zurb/foundation (`4fd252238f165709e77c696cd0459bca95f38479`), no changes are done with **_settings.scss**, but some components are not making it to the css file.

```
git clone git@github.com:zurb/foundation.git
cd foundation
sass --update scss:css
```

produces **foundation.css** which starts with breadcrumbs component parts:

```
/* Accessibility - hides the forward slash */
[aria-label="breadcrumbs"] [aria-hidden="true"]:after {
  content: "/"; }
```

Getting frustrated, any ideas?

`$ sass -v`
`Sass 3.4.1 (Selective Steve)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can tell you sass 3.2.19 works (I just had to downgrade), but that's not an answer, more a work-around.

Comment: You are right. According to https://github.com/zurb/foundation/issues/5636, the pull request for sass is submitted, but the downgrade helped for the moment.